# Can we use windows 8 store app in windows phone 8?

Tags: windows-8, windows-phone-8

I have developed windows 8 store app with XAML and c# so can I use the same app in windows phone 8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not directly. Windows 8 and Windows Phone 8 do share a bit of the underlying WinRT layer, but they are not interchangeable.  There are ways to maximize reuse of your assets - [Portable Class Libraries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/gg597391%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) are a primary mechanism for that - but there are differences in the process lifecycle, storage options, notifications, XAML markup, etc. Of course, the device form factors are also different, so it's likely you'd want to modify the UI even if all of your code were 100% reusable.

[Windows Phone and Windows 8 building together](https://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us/featured/Windows-Phone-8-and-Windows-8-app-development) on the Windows Phone Dev Center is a good place to go to learn about the platform differences and how best to use your current code investment. Also, check out [How to Leverage your Code across WP8 and Windows 8](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2012/3-043) from BUILD 2012.

Comment: So, no matters what coding and designing technology you are using c# and XAML or HTML 5 and CSS both will be same for this scenario ?

Comment: assuming you're starting from a Windows 8 Store app, you'll likely get more reuse in a Windows Phone 8 app from C#/XAML than you will from HTML 5/JavaScript. A Windows 8 Store app built with HTML/JavaScript leverages WinJS and has a different execution model than what you'd do in Windows Phone 8, which would essentially be a browser app running inside of IE.